# How to get site owner using JSOM/REST when logged in user has read only access

Tags: jsom, sharepoint-rest-api

How to get site owner using JSOM/REST when logged in user has read only access.

currentContext.Site.Owner or REST API, fail with unauthorized access error. As it is just readonly property it should be available to all, but it is not.

**EDIT**: using REST I am trying `/_api/site/owner`. or JSOM way `context.Site.Owner`; I need site owner (Primary Administrator)

Any pointer?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Here are related threads for your help. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84168/sharepoint-2013-using-jsom-get-a-list-of-all-sites-user-has-access-too https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/8fa60eaa-1868-4704-a11e-8ba01bb325f0/get-all-sharepoint-sites-in-a-site-collection-to-which-user-has-access-using-javascript-client?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious Hope it helps

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/81759)

Comment: its not read only, its a read-write property. Its read-only in sandbox solutions. Check this [SP.Site.owner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246231.aspx)

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Gautam Sheth, read only term is used for user access

Answer (score 0):

Site Admin or user from specific group? if its from Specific group you can use rest api to get the users. but you have to change group settings to view group members to everyone